# How to calculate the pixels to center a scale?

Tags: javascript, css, zooming, transform

I have 2 images inside of 2 separate divs.
The idea is that when I hover on the full image in the first div, the image in the second div will have a zoom effect and it will be centered, the second div has a 300x300 size.

For now,when I move the mouse over the first image, it is centered correctly in the second div, the only thing is that when I apply a scale of 2 for example, it is not centered, so I am trying to calculate how much I have to add to it be centered when scaled.

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Your Page Title</title>
    <!-- Include jQuery from CDN or from your local project directory -->
    <!-- <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script> -->
    <!-- Include ElevateZoom from your local project directory -->
    <!--<script src="./zoom.js"></script>-->
    <script src="./helloworld.js"></script>
    <!-- Your other head elements -->
    <style>     

.zoom-outer-container {
  border: solid 20px green;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.zoom-inner-container {
  /*border: solid 30px red;*/
  overflow: hidden;
}

.zoom-inner-container img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 1000px;
  transform-origin: center; /* Set the transform origin to the center */
  transition: transform 0.5s ease; /* Adding the transition property for smooth animation */
}


    </style>
</head>
<body>


    <div class="zoom-outer-container" style="border: solid 20px green; display: flex; justify-content: center; overflow: hidden;">
      <div class="zoom-inner-container" style="position: relative;">
        <img style="height: 500px; width: 1000px;" src="download.jfif" alt="Image to Zoom" id="zoom-image" />
        <div class="zoomed-image-container" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 100%; width: 100px; height: 100px; background-image: url(download.jfif); background-size: 150%;"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="mouse-follow-div" style="display: block; background-color: red;overflow: hidden;height: 300px; width: 300px;">
        <img style="height: 500px; width: 1000px;" src="download.jfif" alt="Image to Zoom" id="zoom-image-2" />
    </div>
  </div>

<p>
  Mouse pos global: <b><span id="mouse-pos"></span></b>
  Mouse pos image: <b><span id="mouse-pos-image"></span></b>
</p>
    <script>

            var imageElement = document.getElementById("zoom-image");
            MyLibrary.addZoomTool(imageElement,document.querySelector(".mouse-follow-div"),document.querySelector("#zoom-image-2"), 2); // Zoom in by a scale factor of 1.2

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

js

```
var MyLibrary = {};

MyLibrary.sayHello = function() {
  return "Hello, World!";
};

MyLibrary.addZoomTool = function(imageElement,imageBlock,imageScaled,scaleFactor) {

  const mousePosText = document.getElementById('mouse-pos');
  const mousePosTextImage = document.getElementById('mouse-pos-image');

  let mousePos = { x: undefined, y: undefined };
  let mousePosImage = { x: undefined, y: undefined };
  let inImg = { onImage : false};
  imageElement.addEventListener("mouseenter", function(event) {
    inImg.onImage = true;
    
  });
  imageElement.addEventListener("mousemove", function(event) {

    //const element = document.getElementById('myElement');
    const rect = imageBlock.getBoundingClientRect();
    console.log('--------------------------');
    console.log('Top:', rect.top);
    console.log('Bottom:', rect.bottom);
    console.log('Left:', rect.left);
    console.log('Right:', rect.right);
    console.log('Width:', rect.width);
    console.log('Height:', rect.height);
    console.log('--------------------------');

    //inImg.onImage = true;
    mousePosImage = { x: event.offsetX, y: event.offsetY };
    var scale = scaleFactor || 1.5; 
   //Hay que coger el punto medio del otro ahora
    var centerWidthimageScaled = imageScaled.offsetWidth / 2;
    var centerHeightimageScaled = imageScaled.offsetHeight / 2;

    //150 es el ancho de la caja para que quede centrado
    //imageScaled.style.transform = `scale(${scale})`;

    

    var moveNewX = (mousePosImage.x ) - (300/2);
    var moveNewY = (mousePosImage.y ) - (300/2);
    imageScaled.style.position = "relative";
    //imageScaled.style.right = moveNewX + "px";
    //imageScaled.style.bottom = moveNewY + "px";
    scaleFactor = 1;
    
    //-moveNewX + (-moveNewX)
    //Hay que sumar el pixel que falta tanto en x como en y
    imageScaled.style.transform = `translate(${-moveNewX}px, ${-moveNewY}px) scale(${scaleFactor})`;



 });
  imageElement.addEventListener("mouseleave", function(event) {
    inImg.onImage = false;
    mousePosImage = { x: undefined, y: undefined };
  });

  window.addEventListener('mousemove', (event) => {
    
    //console.log(inImg);
    if(inImg.onImage){
      //console.log("in img");
      //imageElement.style.transform = 'scale(2)';

      //Para saber donde empieza la imagen, hay que coger la posicion del raton y restarle el ancho de la imagen

      
      // Show the mouse-follow-div
      imageBlock.style.display = "block";
  
      // Update the position of the mouse-follow-div based on the mouse cursor
      var mouseX = event.clientX;
      var mouseY = event.clientY;
  
      // Offset the position of the div so it aligns with the cursor
      var offset = 25; // Half the width/height of the div to center it on the cursor
      //imageBlock.style.left = (100 + mouseX - offset) + "px";
      //imageBlock.style.top = (mouseY - offset) + "px";
    }else{
      //console.log("out of img");
      //var mouseFollowDiv = imageBlock;
      //imageBlock.display = "hide";
      //imageBlock.style.display = "none";
    }
   





    mousePos = { x: event.clientX, y: event.clientY };
    


    mousePosText.textContent = `(${mousePos.x}, ${mousePos.y})`;
    mousePosTextImage.textContent = `(${mousePosImage.x}, ${mousePosImage.y})`;
   
  });

  

};
```

Comment: Please clarify, what are you trying to center on, the actual image's center? Or are you trying to center the zoomed image based on the position of the mouse pointer hovering over the first image?

Comment: Yes,sorry for not being clear

Comment: So, if I have an imaginary box drawn around my mouse pointer, say 25pixels x 25pixels, when I hold the mouse pointer over the source image (div 1) the image I want displayed in div 2 would be the contents of the imaginary box around the mouse pointer, but filling the entire div 2. Is this what you are trying to do?